# What does this c# syntax mean?

Tags: c#, syntax, delegates

Hi 
I have a little problem with understanding this kind of syntax

```
public delegate void DelegateType();
BeginInvoke(new DelegateType(functionName));
```

Could somebody tell me what exectly mean new DelegateType(functionName). Why do I have to use new keyword ??

Answer (score 6):

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

A delegate is a type that holds a method.
You're creating a *new* instance of a delegate type, pointing to an existing method.

C# 2 adds an implicit conversion from a method group to any matching delegate type.
However, since `BeginInvoke` doesn't take a specific delegate type (such as `System.Action`), you always need to explicitly create a delegate instance.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement declares a delegate type, the second statement instantiates a new delegate of `DelegateType`.

From the corresponding [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) article (read the article for more information!):

> Once a delegate type has been
>   declared, a delegate object must be
>   created and associated with a
>   particular method. Like all other
>   objects, a new delegate object is
>   created with a new expression. When
>   creating a delegate, however, the
>   argument passed to the new expression
>   is special — it is written like a
>   method call, but without the arguments
>   to the method.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public delegate void DelegateType();
```

This defines the syntax for a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28VS.80%29.aspx).  This is a reference to a method, either static, or an instance method.

When you call [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx), you're passing a delegate as the parameter.  The C# compiler will convert from any explicit delegate type to System.Delegate, but since the parameter is defined as taking any delegate (via [System.Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx)), you must explicitly define the type.

When you specify:

```
new DelegateType(functionName)
```

You're creating a delegate of a specific type (DelegateType), which is then passed to the function.

Often, newer APIs will use a known type, such as [System.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) (which has the same syntax as your DelegateType).  If a method takes an "Action", you would not need the definition above, and you could do:

```
CallMethodTakingAction(functionName);
```

Comment: Nice answer, Can you please let me know how memory is allocated. Am I correct in assuming the compiler allocating memory for delegate?

Comment: @Sandeep: The only real memory allocation is for the delegate itself, which is just a reference.  It's an incredibly small amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

'DelegateType' is only a type of thing, so like any other type, you want to say "here's one instance of this type", you need to use 'new'.